# React Redux get data from dynamic selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having some difficulty accessing the response to a dynamic query.

I think the problem is in my selector.

The selectors :

```
export const getDatasetFetchState = state => state.tracking.dataset

export const getDatasetType = state => state.tracking.datasetType
```

Where dataset is an object that can contain one or more dataset types.

You can see the tree structure here : https://gyazo.com/3f1c228a998b1dde6851296e40a48f73 where 'Document' is dynamically set with my datasetType reducer :

```
const updateDatasetType = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  datasetType: action.value,
})

const handleDatasetSuccess = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  dataset: {
    ...state.dataset,
    [action.datasetType]: {
      ...state[action.datasetType],
      isLoading: false,
      response: action.response,
    },
  },
})
```

In the Front-End I can access the data by :

```
const datasetType = useSelector(getDatasetType)

const {response: responseDataset, error: errorDataset} = useSelector(getDatasetFetchState)
```

And then I try to log the data like this with a map :

```
{datasetType.map(item => console.log(responseDataset[item].data))}
```

where datasetType is an array with one or more strings.

DatasetType is set when I click on a row of an Ag-Grid Grid which displays Data packages with Data Set Types

EDIT :

```
const handleDatasetRequest = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  dataset: {
    ...state.dataset,
    [action.datasetType]: {
      ...state.dataset[action.datasetType],
      hasInit: true,
      isLoading: true,
      response: null,
      error: null,
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: I think you forgot to say that what's the exact problem. what's the problem? what results you get currently? and what's the expected result ?

Comment: I have to display the data from dataset > datasetType (which is dynamic)

Comment: so the `datasetType.map` doesn't work? does it throw any error? did you try : `console.log(datasetType)`?

Comment: and also try `Array.from(datasetType).map` instead of `datasetType.map`

Comment: The map works but I can't access to the data. I got the error : `Cannot read property 'Document' of undefined` and in Redux Dev Tools I can see that dataset is empty because the error occurs before the request calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the error : Cannot read property 'Document' of undefined

```
const {response: responseDataset, error: errorDataset} =
      useSelector(state => state.tracking.dataset) // <-- response is undefined
```

You're trying to access `response` of the the dataset state, but it's not there :

```
const handleDatasetSuccess = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  dataset: {
    ...state.dataset,
    // response is not here
    [action.datasetType]: {
      ...
      response: action.response, // response is here
    },
  },
})
```

So change it to:

```
const dataset = useSelector(state => state.tracking.dataset);

datasetType.map(item => console.log(dataset[item].response.data))
```

> and in Redux Dev Tools I can see that dataset is empty because the error occurs before the request calling

you should also handle this case (before the data comes from the server, the dataset is undefined) :

```
datasetType.map(item => console.log(dataset && dataset[item] && dataset[item].response && dataset[item].response.data))
```

Ps: Also i can see another error in your code:

```
const handleDatasetSuccess = (state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  dataset: {
    ...state.dataset,
    [action.datasetType]: {
      ...state[action.datasetType], // <- Here
```

it should be `state.dataset[action.datasetType]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've got some upgrades. First of all, if I `console.log(dataset[item])` inside the map I can see the data into the item. But the console.log is executed 3 times and the first time it's undefined as you can see here : https://gyazo.com/125afd61bdf0e0657bb9d96e3a02b4eb . So If I `console.log(dataset[item].data)` inside the map I got the same error because the data is null the first and second time. The second time is set with the handleDatasetRequest function which I added in an edit

Comment: @akromx did you noticed my answer update? the part above ps. just using `dataset && dataset[item] && dataset[item].data` ? cause it seems logical that it takes time for server to return `dataset`, so you should handle the `undefined` case. isn't it?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see this line. Yes it works and I modified your answer to access the data directly like this : `console.log(dataset[item] && dataset[item].response && dataset[item].response.data)` . But now I have to handle the undefined case in an ag-grid grid because I want to display the data in it.

Comment: @akromx so just handle it. (`dataset || []` will be `[]` if the dataset is `undefined`). or you can say : `dataset ? (yourprevcode) : []`. or you can show a loading message instead of showing the grid in case of undefined. or thing like this...

Comment: like : `{datasetType.map(item => ((dataset && dataset[item] && dataset[item].response && dataset[item].response.data) || ([]) ))}`